# Dash home not opening

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 12.10. I am trying to open the dash home, but the sidebar disappears until I click out of it. The dash itself never shows up. sometimes the top of the screen fuzzes up a little  bit, but still no dash home.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information about that ? Your question is not clear enough to provide any assistance. Maybe a couple screenshots could help ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (Windows Key):

You can also try reinstalling Unity. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity
```